# DialogFragment buttons color change in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I would like my Fragments to look consistent with the rest of the app and color palette which I applied so I would like to change the colors not only of title, but also of positive/negative buttons:
[image]

I tried to do this like this, but unfortunetaly it doesn't work:

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog d = getDialog();
        int dividerId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
        View divider = d.findViewById(dividerId);

        if(currentapiVersion< Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.dialog_background);
            ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backrepeat_reversed);
        }
        if(currentapiVersion == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            int buttonsId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/negativeButton", null, null);
            Button b = (Button) d.findViewById(buttonsId);
            b.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
        }
        int textViewId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) d.findViewById(textViewId);

        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
    }
```

How to change the color of these buttons? Maybe it is possibile to do it in the whole application through styles.xml file?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you can create the dialog using `AlertDialog` the following worked for me:

```
public class DialogTest extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Test")
                .setMessage("This is a dialog.")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(Color.RED);
        ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great! You saved a lot of my time.

Comment: In the big project this is best solutions.

Answer (score 12):

To change the color of the buttons and checkboxes displayed in Alert dialog you can edit:

> values-21/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
  ...
  <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
  <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
  <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">#00397F</item>
  <item name="android:colorAccent">#0AAEEF</item>
</style>
```

Which will make the dialogs have the selected color for the buttons text and checkboxes:

[image: Dialog] [image: Date picker]

Answer (score 1):

> values-21/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
  ...
  <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
</style>


<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/buttons_color</item>
</style>
```

In Lollipop and above you shouldn't use `android:` prefix